# Seeking a GUI archiver with the ability to exclude files/folders with tickboxes

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, zip, tar, archiving

I've been searching for a GUI tool to create zip, 7-zip or tar archives that will allow me to include and exclude files and folders using a GUI.  The dialog during archive creation should look [something like this.](http://www4.pcmag.com/media/images/246970-jungle-disk-3-1-select-local-files-and-folders-for-backup.jpg)

I know it can be done on the command line, and there's workarounds such as creating an archive with everything then deleting items etc.  But I'm just hoping there is something out there already to do it without other messing around.

Thanks!

Whoops, forgot to mention my OS:  Windows 7

Comment: And your operating system is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are on a Linux system.

If you're not dead-set on having the check-boxes for folder selection, [JBackPack](http://www.nongnu.org/jbackpack/) is a GUI front end for rdiff-backup that looks pretty slick. The file and folder exclude is a list as opposed to check-boxes, and it's probably only going to fit your requirements if you are wanting to backup one folder and then exclude sub-folders and files.

You are fairly light on requirements other than it needs check-boxes for selection...

Answer (score 0):

It's not really hard to do on the command line, once you look it up once.

```
zip -r folder folder.zip -x *.foo
```

That creates a ZIP archive called folder.zip from all files in folder "folder" going down the directory structure recursively (meaning all subfolders and all their files and subfolders are included), excluding all files with the extension `.foo`.